# How to convert a single operation, looping for all records, into oracle

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle-apex

I have a PHOTO table, I have 3 columns in this table: id, MYFILE(blob), ex_id. I wrote a DEMO script that would allow the photo to be captured in second base, into a snapshot column in base 64 format, and to record the JSON response. But I can't debug this script at all, Can I edit it to take all the photos in a loop, I couldn't do it myself, I would be grateful for your help)

this script only works for one record ( where id = 196041;)

```
Declare     
v_clob_post     CLOB;
v_clob          CLOB;
l_body_b        BLOB;
g_EXTERNAL_ID  varchar2(300);   
v_count int;
BEGIN 
select MYFILE INTO l_body_b from PHOTO  where id = 196041;
    apex_json.initialize_clob_output;
    apex_json.open_object;
    apex_json.write('snapshot', blob_to_clob_base64(l_body_b)); 
    apex_json.close_object;
    V_clob  := apex_json.get_clob_output;
    apex_json.free_output;



                    apex_web_service.g_request_headers(1).name := 'Content-Type';  
                    apex_web_service.g_request_headers(1).value := 'application/json';  
                    v_clob_post  := apex_web_service.make_rest_request(p_url => 'myURL',p_http_method => 'POST'
                    ,p_body =>  v_clob );
 apex_json.parse(v_clob_post);     
 g_EXTERNAL_ID := apex_json.get_varchar2(p_path => 'id_document'); -- Obtain access_token
update PHOTO set EXTERNAL_ID = g_EXTERNAL_ID where id = 196041;

end;
```

I want to do this for all table
I want to record whose base, exactly in the Snapshot column. And only in a cycle to take all the photos at a time

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As presented it seems you need a priori knowledge of the photo_ids to process since no source for them is given and you do not use the photo table directly. If that be the case you can accomplish when you want by defining and initializing a collection (array) and loop over the collection. As below:

```
Declare     
v_clob_post     CLOB;
v_clob          CLOB;
l_body_b        BLOB;
g_EXTERNAL_ID  varchar2(300);   
v_count int;

  -- define an array to hold Photo ids
  type photo_list_t is 
        table of integer;
  -- define variable and initialize with Photo ids
   photo_list photo_list_t := photo_list_t(196041,196042,106055, ...);
BEGIN 

-- loop through array
   for i in photo_list.first .. photo_list.last
   loop 
      select MYFILE INTO l_body_b from PHOTO  where id = photo_list(i);    
       .
       . place remainder of existing code here. 
       . 
       update PHOTO set EXTERNAL_ID = g_EXTERNAL_ID where id = photo_list(i);
    end loop;
```

On the other hand if you want to process all the photos you can just loop over the the Photo table itself.

```
Declare     
v_clob_post     CLOB;
v_clob          CLOB;
l_body_b        BLOB;
g_EXTERNAL_ID  varchar2(300);   
v_count int;

BEGIN 

-- loop through Photos
   for my_photo_rec in 
       (select id, myfile 
          from photo 
       )
   loop 
      l_body_b := my_photo_rec.myfile;  -- or update l_body_b following to my_photo_rec.myfile
       .
       . place remainder of existing code here. 
       . 
       update PHOTO set EXTERNAL_ID = g_EXTERNAL_ID where id = my_photo_rec.id;
    end loop;
```